# Future perfect progressive tense with 'if'

Tags: perfect-constructions, future-tense

I would just like to ask if the part of the sentence marked bold is correct.

> My friend started her chemo yesterday and will be checked next month to know **if she will have been responding** well to the treatment.

Comment: Do you know what the sentence (or the part in bold) means? Why do you think it's incorrect? What do you think would be a better choice? Please click on the `edit` link below your question to clarify. By the way, I restricted your question because proofreading requests (of entire sentences) are off-topic on ELL.

Comment: I totally understand what it means. It just so happens that I want to clarify if future perfect progressive is perfectly fine with an if clause. Thanks

Comment: Do you find *...to know whether she will have been responding well to the treatment* odd? (I replaced *if* with *whether*.)

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not idiomatic to use the modal "will" in such forms, except where it means "willing to" (which doesn't make sense with "will have").

"To find out if she has been responding" is more normal

Comment: Even if the finding out happens a month after?

Answer (score 0):

It's grammatically valid as far as I know, but it's not something a native speaker would be likely to use, certainly in that context. It would more likely be "to see if she **has been** responding". That's because it's acceptable, and more natural, for the tense to be relative to the point at which the checking happens. Also because **to see** is more natural to use in that context than **to know**. If you want something more formal, it should be **to find out**. *To know* is not generally used in that sense, because it does not connote the gaining of knowledge, only the possession of knowledge.

The future perfect progressive is more used for actual statements of knowledge, or predictions, rather than things that are to be found out. "She **will have been running** for an hour at that point, so will be tired." In a conditional or other *if* phrase, it would be "if she **has been running** for an hour, she will be tired".

Comment: Even if the reference extends up to the future?

Comment: Even then. It's just not done. I mean, I can see why, by any explanation of the meaning of different tenses in English, you would think it should be that. It just isn't. Sometimes, languages don't make sense - especially English.

Comment: I’ve done a little bit of research. You’re right.

Comment: Yup., I think this comes down to the fact that English doesn't actually have such a thing as a future tense. There are a number of expressions (principally the modal _will_) which often have future meaning, but they don't always, and they're not always required to express futurity.